# Jquery - effect + autohide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery to animate a bit my web site, but I'm having a little issue with some behaviour:

I have a div, which suddenly appears from the top of the page and shakes:

```
$(minipopup).animate({
    marginTop: '+=' + (240) + 'px'
}, 1000);

$(minipopup).effect("shake");
```

This mini popup has an X for closing it, or else, it will auto close after a few seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#minipopup').effect("explode");          
                    }, 10000); 

$('#closePopup').click(function() {
        $('#minipopup').effect("explode");
                    });
```

Everything works, except that, if the user clicks the CLOSE button, he sees the explode effect and the popup effectively dissapears, but after the 10 seconds pass (the one I defined under the setTimeout), the user again sees the popup explosion (just the effect, cause the popup is not there visually). How could I avoid that "ghost" explosion if the user already closed the popup manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your click handler slightly, like this:

```
$('#closePopup').click(function() {
   $('#minipopup').effect("explode", function() {
     $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

This works if you don't need the element again.

Alternatively, if you need the element again, tell your `setTimeout()` function to only do the effect if the element's still visible using the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#minipopup:visible').effect("explode");          
}, 10000);
```

In either of these the selector will stop matching an element you don't want to animate anymore.

Comment: Your second alternative worked perfectly for me. Many thanks.

Comment: @lidermin - Thanks :) Glad it works with minimal changes for you

Answer (score 0):

Set `setTimeout` to a variable, like so:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#minipopup').effect("explode");          
                }, 10000);
```

And then, in your click event, use `clearTimeout` to cancel the timeout:

```
$('#closePopup').click(function() {
        $('#minipopup').effect("explode");
        clearTimeout(timer);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the timer when the user closes the popup.

```
var timer =setTimeout(function() {
        $('#minipopup').effect("explode");          
                    }, 10000); 

$('#closePopup').click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#minipopup').effect("explode");
                    });
```